# generating random numbers within cuda kernel

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, normal-distribution

I am writing a cuda program where I need to generate a random variable which would be generated by following a normal distribution. I want the value of the random variable to be limited between 0 to 8. So I want the random variable to get generated within the kernel function and then the random variable result would be used for further use. I am planning to use the cuRAND library for the purpose. I have been trying to use curand_normal device api to generate the values but without any success. It would be extremely helpful if someone could supply me with the kernel function code. Thank you for all your assistance.

The code provided below is the cpu implementation of what I am searching for in the gpu :

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <random>

    using namespace std;
    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        const int nrolls=10000;  // number of experiments
        const int nstars=100;    // maximum number of stars to distribute
        int i;
        default_random_engine generator;
        normal_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,3);


       for (i=0;i<=nstars;i++)
       {   int number = distribution(generator);
           printf("%d\n\n",number);
        }


        return 0;
    }
```

One thing I would like to add that I don't know C++ and I just wrote this program by following other codes which I saw in other sites. Thanks.

Comment: why don't you post the method you've tried without success?  That's normally a good idea here.  "Write my code for me" type questions aren't as likely to get good results.  Have you looked at the device API example [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/index.html#topic_1_3_6)?  It gives a complete program and one of the `generate_uniform_kernel` options should be pretty close to what you are asking for.

Comment: HI!

HI!
Thank you for your support.I actually gone through the device API example and replicated almost something as it is given over there but only by using XORWOW random generator but the result is not very convincing and given in fraction. I am not sure how would I get a random variable following a normal distribution within the range of 0 to 8. One more thing is that I tried the program mentioned in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832202/cuda-random-number-generating)and I changed curand_uniform to curand_normal in the top device function and I am getting some result.

Comment: Do you want a discrete uniform distribution that takes on the values (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) (i.e. integers) or do you want a continuous valued uniform distribution that takes on values between 0.0 and 8.0 (i.e. floating point numbers.)

Comment: I want discrete number from 0 to 8 with mean of 0

Comment: I don't know how to create a normal distribution with accurate statistics that occupies a limited range.  Do you know how?  What do you do with the tail of the distribution?  And I guess by mean of zero you mean you want only the positive half of a normal distribution centered at zero?   Obviously the mean of the resultant distribution cannot be zero if the range extends from zero to a positive value.  It's not obvious to me that this is a CUDA question.  Do you have a representative non-CUDA (CPU-based) implementation of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Starting with a continuous-valued normal distribution centered at zero (which I know how to generate) how would I create the statistics you want over the discrete range of 0 to 8?  What are the resultant probabilities of each outcome that you expect?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for all your support. I will edit my original question and I will attach the cpu implementation of what I exactly want. I have a successful cpu implementation of what I want in the gpu kernel. Thanks again for your support.

Comment: The code you posted gives a normal distribution with a mean of zero and standard deviation of 3.  So the mean is zero, but the range is not 0 to 8, as you requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an adaptation of [this code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/index.html#topic_1_3_6) which will produce an approximately "normally"-distributed set of random numbers that can take on discrete values between approximately 0 and 8.  I don't understand the request in the comments to have a range of 0 to 8 with a mean of 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include <math.h>
#define SCALE 2.0
#define SHIFT 4.5
#define DISCRETE
#define BLOCKS 1024
#define THREADS 512

#define CUDA_CALL(x) do { if((x) != cudaSuccess) { \
    printf("Error at %s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__); \
    return EXIT_FAILURE;}} while(0)

__global__ void setup_kernel(curandState *state)
{
    int id = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    /* Each thread gets different seed, a different sequence
       number, no offset */
    curand_init(7+id, id, 0, &state[id]);
}



__global__ void generate_normal_kernel(curandState *state,
                                int *result)
{
    int id = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    float x;
    /* Copy state to local memory for efficiency */
    curandState localState = state[id];
    /* Generate pseudo-random uniforms */
    for(int n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        x = (curand_normal(&localState) * SCALE)+SHIFT;
        /* Discretize */
#if defined DISCRETE
        x = truncf(x);
#endif
    }
    /* Copy state back to global memory */
    state[id] = localState;
    /* Store last generated result per thread */
    result[id] = (int) x;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    unsigned int total;
    curandState *devStates;
    int *devResults, *hostResults;
    int device;
    struct cudaDeviceProp properties;

    CUDA_CALL(cudaGetDevice(&device));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaGetDeviceProperties(&properties,device));


    /* Allocate space for results on host */
    hostResults = (int *)calloc(THREADS * BLOCKS, sizeof(int));

    /* Allocate space for results on device */
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc((void **)&devResults, BLOCKS * THREADS *
              sizeof(int)));
    /* Set results to 0 */
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMemset(devResults, 0, THREADS * BLOCKS *
              sizeof(int)));

    /* Allocate space for prng states on device */
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc((void **)&devStates, THREADS * BLOCKS *
                  sizeof(curandState)));

    /* Setup prng states */
    setup_kernel<<<BLOCKS, THREADS>>>(devStates);


    /* Generate and use uniform pseudo-random  */
    generate_normal_kernel<<<BLOCKS, THREADS>>>(devStates, devResults);

    /* Copy device memory to host */
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(hostResults, devResults, BLOCKS * THREADS *
        sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    /* Show result */
    if (THREADS*BLOCKS > 20){
      printf("First 20 stored results:\n");
      for (i=0; i<20; i++)
        printf("%d\n", hostResults[i]);
      }

    total = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < BLOCKS * THREADS; i++) {
        total += hostResults[i];
    }
    printf("Results mean = %f\n", (total/(1.0*BLOCKS*THREADS)));



    /* Cleanup */
    CUDA_CALL(cudaFree(devStates));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaFree(devResults));
    free(hostResults);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You can easily modify this code to produce a continuous-valued normal distribution (of floats) also.

The two parameters of a normal distribution are mean and standard deviation.  These are represented using the SHIFT and SCALE parameters.  SHIFT moves the mean from zero.  SCALE modifies the standard deviation (from 1.0, to whatever SCALE indicates).  So you can play wit the SHIFT and SCALE parameters to get the distribution you want.  Note that truncation of the real-valued output of the random number generator affects the statistics.  You can adjust for this by adjusting SCALE or SHIFT, or you can switch from the `truncf()`, to some flavor of rounding.

You can compile this with:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o uniform uniform.cu
```

assuming you have a cc2.0 or higher GPU.

If not, it's ok to compile with:

```
nvcc -o uniform uniform.cu
```

The compiler warning that double is being demoted to float in this case is OK to ignore.

`THREADS` and `BLOCKS` are arbitrary choices within the limits of the machine.  You can modify these to suit your particular launch configuration of your own code.