# What is the exact behaviour of the CUDA execution?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, visual-studio-debugging

Let's suppose we want to call a global function with the code that follows. Every single thread will have a curandState generator and an array of ints (both properly initialized) that we'll use in order to execute the following code sample:

```
  #define NUMTHREADS 200
  int main(){

    int * result;
    curandState * randState;

    if (cudaMalloc(&randState, NUMTHREADS * sizeof(curandState)) == cudaErrorMemoryAllocation ||
        cudaMalloc(&result, NUMTHREADS * sizeof(int)) == cudaErrorMemoryAllocation){
         cudaDeviceReset();
         exit(-1);
   }

    setup_cuRand <<<1, NUMTHREADS>>> (randState, unsigned(time(NULL)));
    method <<<1, NUMTHREADS>>> (state,result);
    return 1;
}

__global__ void setup_cuRand(curandState * state, unsigned long seed)
{
    int id = threadIdx.x;
    curand_init(seed, id, 0, &state[id]);
}
__global__ void generic method(curandState* state, int * result){

    curandState localState = state[threadIdx.x];
    int num = curand(&localState) % 100;

    if(num > 50) 
       result[threadIdx.x] = threadIdx.x;
    else
       result[threadIdx.x] = -1;
}
```

What would be our execution? I mean, do the threads split into both codes magically and re-join later or how it works? are all 1024 threads in execution at once? this last question is because when i'm debugging on Visual Studio 2013, using Cuda Debugger, when i'm going forward, threadIdx.x allways has a value like `n*32` and until now i tought that 1024 threads could be executed at the same time and now i'm doubtfull

Comment: The CUDA documentation talks a lot about how threads and warps and stuff work; have you read it?

Comment: If you execute that kernel launch on the host, it will fail with an invalid address error because you are passing a host address to the device.

Comment: Unless you used cudamalloc, am i right?

Comment: No, not even if you use `cudaMalloc`.  This construct: `&any_variable_name` cannot ever work with the CUDA kernel call syntax from host code.

Comment: I don't understand exactly the problem, sorry if this is not the place for answering it and i should open a new thread. The problem is with `curandState *state` or with `int * result`? I wrote this sample of code just for this example, but the `&localState` is actually working for me in and i've read it's usage for example at here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832202/cuda-random-number-generating)

Comment: @Kaostias: Nowhere at that link does it show a kernel launch passing a host address as an argument, which is what you are doing in the code above.

Comment: @talonmies I omited all the stuff i have brought just now because of my doubt was more abstract. Is now correct?

Answer (score 3):

The test is likely to be transformed into a predicate that will mean conditional assignment of some value in your region of memory. Should your if be more complex, the threads of a warp would magically *join* after the second part of the `if` clause. Depending on predicate for each thread of a warp, a branch might not even get visited.

When entering a breakpoint, the data will be shown for a specific thread/block id. Which thread/block is followed is given by the **CUDA Debug Focus** setting in NSIGHT for Visual Studio (While debugging with CUDA, enter the NSIGHT menu entry, and select Windows, then CUDA Debug Focus...) By default, thread 0,0,0 will be focused.

Threads are logically executed at the same time, but in practice, you have less than 1024 CUDA-cores per SM. The threads are organized into warps of 32, and warps are scheduled on different execution units by the instruction scheduler.
For 1024 threads, that is 32 warps, the first and last warp are not necessarily executed at the same time precisely.

See [Memory Fence](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-fence-functions) function in cuda documentation for more details, as well as [Synchronization Functions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the ramifications of divergence.

Comment: @Hurkyl, You are right, but I am not sure here is the best place. CUDA programming guide is the relevant resource. You are right to mention it anyways.